# Lumia imaging crop filter

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-10-universal, lumia-imaging-sdk

Hi so I'm making an app  for Windows 10 that requires a user to choose an image and it's going to crop the image to 310*128. I got the file picker code already. But I want to know how to actually crop and save the image and display in image box. I already have the xaml page done

Answer (score 0):

With Lumia Imaging SDK you can both crop the selected image and resize the image. In this answer I assume you actually want to crop, but from the text I could just as well guess you really just want to resize.

For crop, use the [CropEffect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lumia.imaging.transforms.cropeffect.aspx) from Lumia.Imaging.Transforms. Set the CropArea property on it to the object, and then render it. If you are rendering straight to the XAML page I recommend using a `SwapChainPanel` object in XAML and a `SwapChainPanelRenderer` to render on it.

Given that you are loading a StorageFile and rendering to a SwapChainPanel your code might look like something like this:

```
StorageFile file = ...

using (var source = new StorageFileImageSource(file))
using (var crop = new CropEffect(source, new Rect(0, 0, 310, 128))
using (var renderer = new SwapChainPanelRenderer(crop, YourSwapChainPanel))
{
    await renderer.RenderAsync();
}
```

Comment: Thank you! So how would I save the rendered image? And I would I just resize images instead of cropping?.